# Compare array from cell to list of country codes

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation, target

My current cell input for a range of cells is country codes as follows
eg.
NL - UK - FR - BR

I have a list with country codes and I'm trying to check every time a cell has changed if it only contains country codes from the list with separator in-between.

I have the following code thanks to the advice from Tim:

```
Sub ProcessThree(Target As Range)
 If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
'1. replace the wrong seperators
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace " / ", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace " . ", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace " , ", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace " : ", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace " ; ", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace "  ", " - "
'symbols entered without space
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace "/", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace ".", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace ",", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace ":", " - "
ActiveSheet.Range("B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275").Replace ";", " - "



'2. Split cell based on seperator
Dim arr() As String
arr = Split(Target, " - ")
Dim countrycode As Variant
For Each countrycode In arr
MsgBox countrycode
Next


End Sub
```

For the moment stuck on the match part.

I have two questions. Is it not possible to show an entire array outside of the for each when I get the message box for for example ER - DE => it shows the message box twice for each country code - is that normal? and does anyone have a good example on how to match an array with a list/range of country codes? Thanks in advance, already a lot further then when I started.

Comment: What's wrong with the dropdown list? Have you tried `worksheet_change` event?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'not user friendly' ?  If you don't want to use the logic mapped out in the posted code, what do you want to do instead?  How is the code to be called?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the response. The problem with the dropdownlist is that some users would have to select about 50-60 country codes which is why it wasn't considered user friendly. I would like to instead of the dropdown list just let them complete a cell manually and when they enter or leave the cell have a check that can tell if it only contains country codes from the list or the seperator "-". Does that make sense?

Comment: A UserForm with a multiselect list or a bunch of checkboxes might be easier for your users?

Comment: Yes thought about that - but because of the large range where country codes need to be completed it isn't really feasible. Any other ideas? I was thinking that a for loop might do the trick but haven't found a good example on here

Comment: Take the user-supplied value, normalize the separator by replacing comma, space etc with "-", then split on "-" and loop over the resulting array, checking each value against your list using something like `Match()` (this will be fast if you run it against the range containing the list).  Build a string containing the matched values - you can put this back in the cell.  Show the user a messagebox with the values you removed.  Still not great for your users though - they'd have the remember the list from the messagebox and then go back and fix their entry (or entries)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks I'll give this a try :) Will get back to you

Comment: @TimWilliams I updated the post cuz I didn't have enough room in the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const THE_RANGE = "B199:B218,B223:B242,B247:B261,B266:B275"
    Const SEP As String = "-"
    
    Dim c As Range, arr, s As String, e, v, rngList As Range, msg As String
    
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'single-cell updates only
    
    'is the change in the range of interest?
    Set c = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range(THE_RANGE))
    If c Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no intersect
    
    v = Trim(UCase(c.Value))      'trim and upper-case the user-entered value
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub   'no content
    
    'normalize to wanted separator
    For Each e In Array("/", ".", ",", ":", ";", " ")
        v = Replace(v, e, SEP)
    Next e
    
    Set rngList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lists").Range("A1:A20") 'for example
    arr = Split(v, SEP)
    
    For Each e In arr
        e = Trim(e)
        If Len(e) > 0 Then
            'is this code in the list
            If IsError(Application.Match(e, rngList, 0)) Then
                msg = msg & IIf(Len(msg) > 0, vbLf, "") & e 'add to error message
            Else
                'don't add items already added
                If Instr(SEP & s & SEP, e) = 0 Then
                    s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, SEP, "") & e  'goes back into cell...
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next e
    Application.EnableEvents = False  'don't re-trigger the event...
    Target.Value = s
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
    'any codes removed?
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following country codes are not valid:" & vbLf & msg, vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow Tim, thanks a lot - the solution works perfectly!! this was exactly what I was looking to do - very big thank you :)

Comment: You have already helped to much, but idea on how to remove duplicates? I was thinking to use the match again but reads everything in c as one value for the match right?
 ` If IsError(Application.Match(e, rngList, 0)) Then
                msg = msg & IIf(Len(msg) > 0, vbLf, "") & e 'add to error message
            Else
             If IsError(Application.Match(e, c, 0)) Then
              s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, SEP, "")  'goes back into cell...
             Else
                s = s & IIf(Len(s) > 0, SEP, "") & e  'goes back into cell...
                End If
            End if`

Comment: Added a check using `Instr()` (untested but should be OK)

Comment: it worked like a charm, thanks again - you rock!